# how to join two tables using iron python

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

i am trying to build a table using two different tables with a common column and looking to do outer join on these tables like 
table 1 has 2 columns employer,department
table 2 has 2 columns department,salary
so the output table will be employer,department,salary with unique combinations.Please help me out .thank you

Comment: Have you looked into do this in the information designer? What is the source of the two datasets?

Comment: Hi scsimon, those two tables are not coming from data source,tables are coming from API